# Use of would and conditional

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals

I'm just wondering whether would means possible in the following sentences? It's ambiguous on what it's used to talk about an unreal situation or to make suggestions sound less definite. I'm confused to determine that.

In the use of type 2 conditional which is usually used to talk about something not happening, is it also used to make statements sound tentative?

1. A student asking his teacher to do a lesson in grammar so he says:
   It **would** be great to make a video about embedded clauses.
2. It would be nice if you could help me a bith with the homework.
3. If you moved your chair a bit, we could all sit down.

Comment: An 'unreal' situation, in this context, doesn't have to be an _unrealistic_ one. Suggesting that something that hasn't happened yet 'would be good/nice/great' is both a conditional and a polite way of asking for it to be done.

Comment: But I can also use "will" for something that hasn't happened. That's what has been making me confused. It will/would be very expensive to stay in a hotel. This is something that hasn't happnet. And by the way, there is no conditional form in the sentence "would be great..."

Comment: I meant 'it would be great if...', of course! 'It will be very expensive to stay in a hotel' suggests that you are, nevertheless, planning to do so. 'It would be very expensive' refers to a hypothetical stay - perhaps comparing the price with other possible forms of accommodation.

Comment: So, "it would be great if making a video about embeded clauses" (= in reality, he/she doesn't make a video, it is not great), am I right?

Comment: "It would be great _if you made/were to make_ a video about embedded clauses."  The student says that, if such a video existed, it would be very useful. It's a hint that they would like their teacher to make one.

Comment: Can I also say "it will be great if you make a video about embedded clauses?" Saying "it will be great if...," it means the video exist. Is my understanding right? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Saying "it will be great if..." implies that the teacher has said that they probably will do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120794/discussion-between-jembot-and-kate-bunting).

Comment: You said the situation is hypotheical.  What is "hypothetical"?

Comment: Answered in chat.